# LUA- display new image disables removing an event

Tags: image, events, object, lua, coronasdk

I'm having a trouble right now.
I have a matrix of objects. Each object is an image and has an event listener that is triggered when i tap the object.
the event changes the picture, using display.newImage() property.
at some point i want to remove the event listener. I found out that the removing isn't working on the images i tapped on. I can't really understand why, because clearly the event still exists after i tap one time on the image (i know that because i can tap and change the image more the once)... so I really don't know what the problem is.
thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are only registering the touch event ONCE for each image.

Also remember that the  `touch` event is *propagating* (It will continue to trigger touch events for images that are underneath the first image) In order to prevent the touch event from propagating you need to `return true` at the end of your touch handler.

I would recommend adding `print("Registered Touch Event")` statements to check and make sure things are happening the way you want them.